# Calculating the commutator subgroup.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to find the commutator subgroup ($G^k$, $k=1,2,..$) of such matrix group:$$
   \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & * & * \\
    0 & * & 0 \\
    0 & * & * \\
  \end{array}\right)$$

I have multiplied them "by hands" and I got that $G^1=  \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & * & * \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & * & 1 \\
  \end{array}\right)$,
$G^2= \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
    1 & * & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
  \end{array}\right)$, $G^3=E$.

Did I do it in the right way? Or maybe you can suggest a more elegant way of calculating?

Comment: CAn you more explain that what is exactly your matrix group and over what?Natural number or $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: That's right for matrices over any field except ${\mathbb F}_2$, where $G^2=1$.

Comment: Would you please give a definition of your group and notation?